# Supplier tipo INT que devuelva el valor que ingreso + Predicate que diga si el número que ingreso es primo o no

Tags: java, números-primos

Tengo la siguiente tarea:

**Escribir un Supplier de tipo  que devuelva un numero leído por pantalla con una expresión lambda de bloque**

**Escribir un Predicate que nos diga si el número ingresado es primo con una expresiónlambda de bloque que tenga un bucle for. Aplicarlo al resultado del supplier**

**Debe devolver:**

*Escriba un número entero por pantalla
24
numero generado por el supplier 24 no es primo*

**o**

*Escriba un número entero por pantalla
23
El numero generado por el supplierPantalla 23 es primo*

Según si el número introducido es primo o no.

El código que he hecho yo es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


public class Ejercicio4 {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     
    Supplier <Integer> numeroPorPantalla = () ->{
    int n;   
    System.out.println("Escriba un número entero por pantalla");
    n=teclado.nextInt();
    return n;
     
    };
   
   Predicate<Integer> esPrimo = (n) -> {
    int a = 0;
    int i;
    
    for (i=1; i<= n; i++) {
        if (n % 1 == 0) {
            a++;
        }
    }
       if (a != 2) {
           System.out.println("El número generado por el supplierPantalla "+numeroPorPantalla.get()+" no es primo");
       } else {
           System.out.println("El número generado por el supplierPantalla "+numeroPorPantalla.get()+" es primo");
       }
        return true ;
 };
   
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.print(esPrimo.test(numeroPorPantalla.get()));
   
    
    }
    

    }
```

Y los problemas que tengo al ejecutar son:

- me pide ingresar 2 veces el valor, cuando solo debería ser una.
- el bucle FOR no me está funcionando bien ya que siempre me devuelve que no es primo
- También me devuelve el "true" del predicate y no debería devolver nada.

Agradezco la ayuda que se me pueda dar.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes Clavillo.

Sobre tus dos últimas preguntas, tienes el bucle mal definido. Estás continuamente preguntando por n % 1, y esta operación siempre te va a devolver 0, por lo tanto  siempre te escribirá no primo (el número 1 si te dirá que es primo)

El retorno también está mal colocado, cuando haces la evaluación de la variable "a" únicamente se escribe, pero el retorno true está posterior a esta comprobación.

Sobre el porque está escribiendo dos veces, es porque realmente lo estás haciendo dos veces. Cuando instancias la clase Supplier, te obliga a sobreescribir su método get(). Ejemplo con el fuente:

```
Supplier<Integer> supplier = new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
};
```

Cuando arranca el proceso main(), se crea la primera vez el Supplier pidiendo introducir los datos por pantalla. Luego, antes de terminar el proceso de main(), estás llamando de nuevo al método get() del Supplier

```
 System.out.print(esPrimo.test(numeroPorPantalla.get()));
```

Por lo que ejecutas de nuevo ese trozo de código.
Te aconsejo que vayas practicando con las herramientas de debug que suelen tener la mayoría de IDEs, ya que te van a permitir poder detectar estos errores de forma sencilla.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola buenas, en primer lugar muchas gracias por la ayuda pero, respecto al retorno, al ser una empresión lambda de bloque me pide que haya un retorno al final para que funcione, es por eso que no logro hacer funcionar el bucle y, al mismo tiempo, el return de la expresión lambda.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. En principio, mientras que asegures el retorno en ambos casos, no deberías tener ningún problema. Por ejemplo: